# PHP спарсить музыку вконтакте

Tags: парсер

Подскажите, каким образом можно спарсить сразу весь список аудиозаписей своих или другого пользователя используя php? Там ведь сразу не показывает весь список аудиозаписей, а добавляет только по прокрутке вниз. Каким образом можно получить весь список музыки для парсинга? Нужен вариант именно без VK API.

Comment: юзай vk api, там все это есть, хорошо и удобно реализовано

Comment: vk api вроде-бы давно запретили по поводу музыки

Comment: Мне нужен вариант без VK API.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/340810/ - вот код на nodejs. Когда первый раз увидел статью, он работал (я его несколько дописал, чтобы сгенерировать страницу со ссылками и потом их скачать). Генерируемые ссылки привязаны к ip, но не привязаны к сессии. Вряд ли с php получится легко что-то сделать, потому что там автор копировал код с vk в свой скрипт - в случае другого языка с ним придётся разбираться и переписывать.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант без API - curl... Но придется изрядно помучатся с авторизацией, а что самое главное - скорее всего на php ты это не сделаешь (хотя, кажись есть библиотека для выполнения JS, как в браузерах), так как музыка там подгружается AJAX-ом

Comment: Ну можно использовать JS + PHP, а так по-моему нужна кука remixsid

Comment: Как именно получить список всех аудиозаписей?